# Font Awesome is not showing but https link works

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am creating a page where the user is formatting their own text. I am using font awesome for the buttons and I have come across an issue.

When I download font awesome v5.8.1 the fonts do not show. However when I use the https link the fonts show. They are the same file.

The path to the downloaded css file is correct because I have other css files in that folder and they show fine. I also use jQuery CDN for jQuery and jQuery UI that work fine.

So the firewall nor the anti-virus programs should not be blocking http or https links.

With the downloaded css file 
[image]

With the https link (https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css)
[image]

Comment: Why don't you check the console with the downloaded file loaded? Check the source too. Make sure the CSS file is loaded without any error

Comment: Show your code. Also, you know that there already exists such tools? CKEditor is one of the best

Comment: If you show the code that is including the CSS, it would be a lot easier to help.

Comment: Please explain what “When I download font awesome v5.8.1” actually means. _“They are the same file”_ - so you did download _just_ the CSS file then, nothing else? Of course that doesn’t work, the CSS is referring to multiple font files at the end using relative paths. A look into the browser console would have told you that those error out with 404s in that case.

Comment: In case you downladed all.css and uploaded just that to your server, it won't work because the .css attempts to use resources that are included in the full ZIP. You need to unzip the entire .ZIP to your webserver and maintain the directory-strucure.